# dark current of PIN photodidoe

Tags: current, analog, photodiode

I am now learning about the dark current of PIN photodiode and wonder that if no reversed bias voltage is applied to the photodiode, whether the dark current is 0 or not? If not, how small it would be? nA or pA?

Besides, whether the dark current is DC current or AC current?

Answer (score 1):

The dark current is DC and is directly dependent of the bias voltage. There is theoretically no dark current without bias. You can read more in section 1-3 of this document: http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/e02_handbook_si_photodiode.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! But in some datasheets of photodidoe, it said that even if bias voltage is 0, a small dark current(about 0.01nA) still exists. Does it mean that in the real case, dark current can not be 0?